# How to translate this jsonb SQL query to an Active Record query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

The following data is present in my `Color` ActiveRecord model:

| id | colored_things |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `[{"thing" : "cup", "color": "red"}, {"thing" : "car", "color": "blue"}]` |
| 2 | `[{"thing" : "other", "color": "green"}, {"thing" : "tile", "color": "reddish"}]` |
| 3 | `[{"thing" : "unknown", "color": "red"}]` |
| 4 | `[{"thing" : "basket", "color": "velvet or red or purple"}]` |

The `colored_things` column is defined as jsonb.

I am trying to search on all `"color"` keys to get values that are *like* a certain search term. This SQL query (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5cb4b/19)) does that:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT C.*
FROM colors AS C,
jsonb_array_elements(colored_things) AS colorvalues(colorvalue)
WHERE colorvalue->>'color' ILIKE '%pur%';
```

Now I would love to translate this query to a proper Active Record query, but the below does not work:

```rb
Color.joins(jsonb_array_elements(colored_things) AS colorvalues(colorvalue))
  .where("colorvalue->>'color' ILIKE '%?%'", some_search_term)
  .distinct
```

This gives me the error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "colors")

Can someone point me in the proper direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing doesn't change that much if you use ActiveRecord, and IMO it remains more readable if you leave your query as it's in SQL.

For making it work you can use `from`, and there pass the *raw* `FROM` clause you currently have:

```
from("colors AS c, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(colored_things) AS colorvalues(colorvalue)")
```

Having that your tables and aliases are already accessible, so you can chain the `WHERE` and `SELECT` clause, with their corresponding AR methods:

```
Color
  .from("colors AS c, JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(colored_things) AS colorvalues(colorvalue)")
  .where("colorvalue->>'color' ILIKE '%pur%'")
  .select("DISTINCT c.*")
```

Notice `where("colorvalue->>'color' ILIKE '%?%'", value)` will not work because `value` is quoted by the ORM, so instead you have to construct the "`%value%`" and use it as the bound value:

```
where("colorvalue->>'color' ILIKE ?", "%#{value}%")
```

Comment: Of course, `from` is the missing puzzle piece! Thanks a lot, great answer :-) (Main reason to try doing this in ActiveRecord was to prevent some headaches over scrubbing user input. I agree with you that pure SQL is often much more readable.)

Comment: `from` covers many cases like this, but sadly it lacks documentation. Shameless plug, I wrote a [gem](https://github.com/sebastian-palma/yesql) that you can use in these situations.